# Some assistance, please

Tags: support, specific-question, closed-questions

I am not disputing the closure of [my question on end-of-humanity SF and politics](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/42648/end-of-humanity-sf), but how could I edit it so that it falls within the rules of this Exchange? Seems I'm not the only one interested, it has four upvotes and one person favorited it.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you can just go to the question and edit it, like you would a question that was open. If I'm not mistaken, this would automatically queue it for review by a moderator to see if the edit made it pass muster.

On a personal note, I think your last paragraph, "are there any scholarly works..." is what prompted people to vote to close, since it made it seem like an open ended list question. However, if you reworded it to focus on the penultimate paragraph, it can be a very interesting question - "What effect did nuclear fears have on the science fiction of the early cold war?" is a great question. Might still be a bit too broad, but interesting.

Comment: Yes, it is definitely the open-ended list part that was the problem. If what you really want is a list of works that contain the same theme, then you'll have to ask it somewhere else. Chat can be good for this.

Comment: Not necessarily review by a moderator, it just puts it in the standard reopen queue for anyone with 3k rep.

Comment: I've edited it, hope it's acceptable now.

Comment: @EugeneSeidel In all honesty, I think the edit made it worse.  Calling for people's opinions tends to send up red flags on the SE platform.  I'm going to edit out the last sentence for you, but feel free to roll-back or edit it further if you disagree.

Comment: @Beofett OK, thanks.